# how can I cause any change to a variable in an internal function to affect main variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I know java script doesn't have call by reference. So how can I solve this?

```
(function($){

$.fn.extend({

    something: function(options) {
        var Status;
        var defaults = {
            regex:/^([\u0600-\u06FF]|\s)*$/,
            errortxt:"Invalid input",
            emptytxt:"It should not be empty"
        }
        var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
        $(this).bind('change', function () { 
            Status = true;
             $(this).each(function() {
                /*variables*/
                var necessaryElement;
                if (options.regex && options.errortxt && options.errorsection)
                {
                    var filter = options.regex;
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var wrongMessage = options.errortxt;
                    var $errordiv = $("[ID$="+options.errorsection+"]");
                } else{ 
                    console.log("Error : Not enough arguments for invoking something Plugin");
                }
                if (options.emptytxt)
                {
                    var noMessage = options.emptytxt;
                    necessaryElement = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    necessaryElement = false;
                }
                var elementvalue = $this.val();

                /* Methods */
                if (elementvalue != "" && necessaryElement) {
                    if (filter.test(elementvalue)){
                        $this.removeClass("error").addClass("ok");
                        $errordiv.fadeOut(300);
                    } else {
                        Status = false;
                        $this.removeClass("ok").addClass("error");
                        $errordiv.fadeIn(200);
                        $errordiv.text(wrongMessage);
                    }
                } else if (elementvalue == "" && necessaryElement) {
                    Status = false;
                    $this.removeClass("ok").addClass("error");
                    $errordiv.fadeIn(200);
                    $errordiv.text(noMessage);
                }
            });
        });
        return Status;
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

and I call it in another js in this way:

```
var myarray=new Array();
myarray[0] = $('#selector').something({
regex:/^([\u0600-\u06FF]|\s)*$/,
// another options
});
$('#selector').change(function (){
    alert (myarray[0]);
});
```

but it alerts `undefined`.

If I change `var Status` to `var Status= true` Then it always alerts `true`.

Can anyone help me?  How I can change the code to return the desired `Status`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit : Trying to be clearer.

`Something()` returns a value which is modified by `change`.
So when you call `something` you return the value unmodified.
Then you call `change` that will change the value, but it's not passed by reference in the array so it won't change anything.

You may want to use the `data` function available on JQuery objects for keeping data.
Here is a simplified version:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({

    something: function(options) {

        $(this).bind('change', function () {
            $(this).data('status','true');
        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myarray=new Array();
    myarray[0] = $('#selector').something({
    regex:/^([\u0600-\u06FF]|\s)*$/
    });
    $('#selector').change(function (){
        alert ($(this).data('status'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at the exemple using `data` function. It may help you